# Number of rows in each column of AWS Athena Table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Is there any way to find the total number of rows in the AWS Athena table. I used the following SQL query which only shows the columns and their data types.

```
DESCRIBE  Table_name
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried a simple query?

```
select count(*)
from tablename;
```